# How to recognize file download

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to download files from internet inside the app using internal web browser and save them to some custom path.
I think I should use UIWebViewDelegate and intercept lick clicks in

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

But here's my question: how can I know when the file is being downloaded (not just other webpage being opened).
I thought I could parse the link and determine if the extension is png, doc or something. But the problem is I need to be able to download the files of any type.

Thank you for any help.

UPDATE:
How can I recognize that this is link is actually for downloading. E.g. in this case -> etextlib.ru/Book/DownLoadPDFFile/19036 <- the link does not have recognizable extension.

Comment: This is what I thought to be the way to intercept the attempt to download a file. What other options do I have?

Comment: Does the web view contain your website, or can the user browse to anything?

Comment: @Evgeniy The easiest way would be to use a 3rd party that does everything for you. See my answer.

Comment: The user can browse anything.

Comment: How did you manage to fix this ?

Comment: See the accepted answer. I believe, I went with option 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have two ways to go about this in my opinion, and both involve implementing `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`:

1. Define which file types you want to download and check for them in the tapped link.
2. On any tap the user makes on a link, do the following

   - If the link is to a known file type, download it.
   - If the link is a web page (htm, html, asp, ...), just open it
   - Any other case: Ask user whether he wants to download the link as a file.

Comment: So I think the best solution would be, check if the link is a web page. If NOT, download it (just in case - ask user whether he wants to download it).

Comment: Yes, although it might not be clear what "a web page" is - there are quite a lot of possible ways to name a webpage ...

Comment: How can I recognize that this is link is actually for downloading. E.g. in this case -> http://www.etextlib.ru/Book/DownLoadPDFFile/19036 <- the link does not have recognizable extension.

Answer (score 0):

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Creating a Download Task

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/download.zip"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectorie

sInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
    return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

just check `[request.URL.absoluteString pathExtension]` to see the type of link and do what you want

Comment: This won't work for downloads that are served dynamically (e.g. http://example.com/download.php?id=123)

Comment: I think there is no way to get content type before server return it, so you should make request to every URL and check what you receive